# Who is accessing my DynamodDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Lately, I noticed an unexpected increase in read accesses on one of my tables in DynamodDB. I thought I could turn to AWS CloudTrail to find out who is accessing it (source IP addresses, etc.). However, it turns out that CloudTrail doesn't have support for DynamodDB.

Given that AWS CloudTrail doesn't support DynamodDB, what are my options for discovering who is accessing my DynanodDB table?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could DENY access to all IAM Users, Groups and Roles that don't have a need to access that DynamoDB table, and then see who complains!

See: [IAM Policy Evaluation Logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_EvaluationLogic.html)